# Swift- Simplest way to play system default sounds in Cocoa(macOS,OS X)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am learning Cocoa Programming.

I only need to play sounds when an async task is done or failed in my very own Cocoa project.

So I would like to know what is the simplest way.

Although It should be quite easy, I have not found it out in Swift.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Probably, the easiest way is to use `NSSound`. For example:

```
NSSound(named: "Purr")?.play()
```

From Apple documentation:

> If there’s no known NSSound object with soundName, this method tries
>   to create one by searching for sound files in the application’s main
>   bundle (see NSBundle for a description of how the bundle’s contents
>   are searched). If no sound file can be located in the application main
>   bundle, the following directories are searched in order:
>
> - ~/Library/Sounds
> - /Library/Sounds
> - /Network/Library/Sounds
> - /System/Library/Sounds
>
> If you want to play the system beep sound, use the `NSBeep` function.

Comment: This is good and very simple! I did not wanted to import any class just for playing default sounds. thanks.

Comment: Please note that in Swift 3.0, macOS High Sierra you have to use: `NSSound(named: NSSound.Name(rawValue: "Purr"))?.play()` instead.

Comment: This has changed by Swift 4. The line is now `NSSound(named: NSSound.Name("Purr"))?.play()`  EDIT kitsune is correct, but the rawValue descriptor is not needed.

Comment: What should I import to use NSSound? Swift shows Use of unresolved identifier 'NSSound'

Comment: @bodich if you [google `NSSound`](https://www.google.com/search?q=NSSound), the first result is [the Apple documentation for it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssound). In there, you'll see it's in AppKit.

Comment: @bodich In Xcode, you can press ⌘⇧O and type `NSSound`. Press ↩ and it will show you the header/interface for `NSSound`. In [the navigation bar at the top](https://i.imgur.com/ahdOuux.png), you'll see it's in AppKit.

Comment: @bodich in Xcode, you can open the Developer Documentation window (in the Window menu, or by pressing ⌘⇧0) and search `NSSound`. There, [you'll see it's in AppKit](https://i.imgur.com/AWa1E8N.png)

Answer (score 21):

Simplest? Put this in a Swift file in your project:

## Swift 4.2 through 5.3

```swift
import AppKit



public extension NSSound {
    static let basso     = NSSound(named: .basso)
    static let blow      = NSSound(named: .blow)
    static let bottle    = NSSound(named: .bottle)
    static let frog      = NSSound(named: .frog)
    static let funk      = NSSound(named: .funk)
    static let glass     = NSSound(named: .glass)
    static let hero      = NSSound(named: .hero)
    static let morse     = NSSound(named: .morse)
    static let ping      = NSSound(named: .ping)
    static let pop       = NSSound(named: .pop)
    static let purr      = NSSound(named: .purr)
    static let sosumi    = NSSound(named: .sosumi)
    static let submarine = NSSound(named: .submarine)
    static let tink      = NSSound(named: .tink)
}



public extension NSSound.Name {
    static let basso     = NSSound.Name("Basso")
    static let blow      = NSSound.Name("Blow")
    static let bottle    = NSSound.Name("Bottle")
    static let frog      = NSSound.Name("Frog")
    static let funk      = NSSound.Name("Funk")
    static let glass     = NSSound.Name("Glass")
    static let hero      = NSSound.Name("Hero")
    static let morse     = NSSound.Name("Morse")
    static let ping      = NSSound.Name("Ping")
    static let pop       = NSSound.Name("Pop")
    static let purr      = NSSound.Name("Purr")
    static let sosumi    = NSSound.Name("Sosumi")
    static let submarine = NSSound.Name("Submarine")
    static let tink      = NSSound.Name("Tink")
}
```

## Swift 3.2 through 4.1

```swift
import AppKit



public extension NSSound {
    
    #if !swift(>=4)
    private convenience init?(named name: Name) {
        self.init(named: name as String)
    }
    #endif
    
    public static let basso     = NSSound(named: .basso)
    public static let blow      = NSSound(named: .blow)
    public static let bottle    = NSSound(named: .bottle)
    public static let frog      = NSSound(named: .frog)
    public static let funk      = NSSound(named: .funk)
    public static let glass     = NSSound(named: .glass)
    public static let hero      = NSSound(named: .hero)
    public static let morse     = NSSound(named: .morse)
    public static let ping      = NSSound(named: .ping)
    public static let pop       = NSSound(named: .pop)
    public static let purr      = NSSound(named: .purr)
    public static let sosumi    = NSSound(named: .sosumi)
    public static let submarine = NSSound(named: .submarine)
    public static let tink      = NSSound(named: .tink)
}



public extension NSSound.Name {
    
    #if !swift(>=4)
    private convenience init(_ rawValue: String) {
        self.init(string: rawValue)
    }
    #endif
    
    public static let basso     = NSSound.Name("Basso")
    public static let blow      = NSSound.Name("Blow")
    public static let bottle    = NSSound.Name("Bottle")
    public static let frog      = NSSound.Name("Frog")
    public static let funk      = NSSound.Name("Funk")
    public static let glass     = NSSound.Name("Glass")
    public static let hero      = NSSound.Name("Hero")
    public static let morse     = NSSound.Name("Morse")
    public static let ping      = NSSound.Name("Ping")
    public static let pop       = NSSound.Name("Pop")
    public static let purr      = NSSound.Name("Purr")
    public static let sosumi    = NSSound.Name("Sosumi")
    public static let submarine = NSSound.Name("Submarine")
    public static let tink      = NSSound.Name("Tink")
}
```

Then you can very simply play any system sound like this:

```
NSSound.glass?.play()
```

---

Note that you can also make the system play the default error sound like this:

## Swift 4.0 and up (tested through 5.3)

```
NSSound.beep()
```

## Swift 1-3 and Objective-C

```
NSBeep()
```

Comment: Extending `NSSound` here is good, but you should ***not*** extend `NSSound.Name` as it's actually a type alias for `String` meaning you now have `String.funk`, `String.sosumi`, etc., which clutters your global API for `String`.

Answer (score 7):

I found this to work in Version 8.3.3 Playground:

```
import AudioToolbox
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1209) //plays a beep tone
```

Comment: How do I know what magic number to give to this function call?

Comment: [This website](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary) has a list of the sound numbers, but it's for iOS so not all of them work on macOS. `1209` seems to play "dtmf-9.caf."

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 4, you can use NSSound.beep() which should play the system beep set in the System Preferences.

Answer (score 4):

This came up in my search today so I've cleaned up Ky.'s excellent answer a little bit for the next person:

```swift
import AppKit

public extension NSSound {

    enum Sound: String {
        case basso = "Basso"
        case blow = "Blow"
        case bottle = "Bottle"
        case frog = "Frog"
        case funk = "Funk"
        case glass = "Glass"
        case hero = "Hero"
        case morse = "Morse"
        case ping = "Ping"
        case pop = "Pop"
        case purr = "Purr"
        case sosumi = "Sosumi"
        case submarine = "Submarine"
        case tink = "Tink"
    }

    static func play(_ sound: Sound) {
        NSSound(named: NSSound.Name(sound.rawValue))?.play()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
NSSound.play(.submarine)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, with import for macOS 10.9+ (Xcode 9.0+): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssound/2903487-beep

```
import AppKit

NSSound.beep()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another very short way to write is:

```
NSSound.init(named: "Pop")?.play()
```